# Running a daily task via Window Task Scheduler with condition of internet access

Tags: windows, events, scheduled-tasks, autohotkey

I want an AutoHotkey task to run daily at a specific time under the condition that there is internet access on my notebook, as it needs to open a website. If there is no internet access, run task as soon as it becomes available. Using Windows Task Scheduler, there is no apparent setting for this condition. Maybe there is a way to build a custom event trigger which checks for internet connection?

I couldn't find anything about this on the internet, despite my requirement being quite basic for a scheduled task.

The option "Start only if the following network connection is available: Any connection" in the Conditions tab of my task doesn't work. I was offline in airplane mode and the task still triggered. Probably it detects my Hyper-V Network-Adapters "vEthernet" and thus the condition is true. I also don't want to set a specific WiFi Network there, as I could be at home or at uni when the task gets triggered. So far the trigger for my task is the system clock.

Comment: Just [for reference this AHK Board](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/111086-solved-check-if-connected-to-the-internet/) about getting the internet connection state. Note that you cannot check internet connection, you can only check being plugged. But you can test the connection (not the same) as [EJE suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56297288/4575793) - assuming "https://google.com will never be down". [The first link](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/111086-solved-check-if-connected-to-the-internet/) suggests pinging the 13 root DNS servers for more robustness instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried anything yet in AutoHotkey? I would recommend posting your code if you have or making an attempt first. Generally speaking, we won't write your code for you, but we will gladly help with specific problems or issues.

To get you started, I would recommend using [SetTimer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm) to regularly check what time it is. Once it has a match to your desired time, deactivate timer and check if connected to the internet (see below). If connected, do the task(s) you mention and reactivate timer. If it's not, keep rechecking every 30 sec. (or whatever you want) until connected.

Checking internet connectivity isn't quite as straight-forward, but here is a simplified example of what I occasionally use.

```
f1::
If NetChk( "https://www.google.com" )
    MsgBox , Success!
Else
    MsgBox , Nope... :(
Return

NetChk( sAddress )
{
    ComObjError( false )
    oWHR := ComObjCreate( "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" )
    oWHR.Open( "GET" , sAddress )
    oWHR.Send()
    Return oWHR.ResponseText
}
```

Comment: Regarding the scheduling I haven't tried anything yet in AutoHotkey. I thought it would be easier to let the windows build-in Task Scheduler handle it, and then letting it run the main AHK-script when the time is right and the conditions are met.  Thus I didn't post my AHK-code as it is quite irrelevant to my problem with Windows Task Scheduler.

Thanks for tips with the AHK functions. If the scheduling isn't easily doable with Windows Task Scheduler, I think I'll have to code the logic myself into the AHK script, and let it always run indefinitely from startup :/

Comment: Although `SetTimer` would run constantly, it can be at intervals you specify, like once every second, 30 sec, one hour, etc. Since it would only be comparing time, it's not taxing on system resources. I would recommend using it instead of the built-in task scheduler. Another advantage is that it will easily work on another computer if you have need to work on a different system without any fuss.

Comment: Good points @EJE and +1 - but you could still use the *Windows Task Scheduler* to deal with timing ("daily") and then just check the internet connection in a loop and finish the task as soon as connected. Run this as singleton and re-run it regularly. This means that it is not running as long as the script is done.